# Python 2.x with Tkinter grid text update

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to code a Python and Tkinter App, with a kind of table on it.

So with Tkinter I was able to create a "Excel- licke" sheet with some rows and columns.

But now I want to update the values periodically (once every 30 second).
If I loop the grid, then the program get slower, the longer it runs.
I guess, it is not the best way to create the grid alway new.

So how can a grid be made and only the values will be updated in the loop?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: show us the code, it isn't enough to describe the issue in words as it gives us nothing to work from to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is pretty much what you wrote: create the widgets once, then create a loop to update the values periodically.

Here's an example:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import random

class Table(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, rows=10, columns=10):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        self.widgets = []
        for r in range(rows):
            row = []
            self.widgets.append(row)
            for c in range(columns):
                cell = tk.Label(self)
                cell.grid(row=r, column=c, sticky="nsew")
                row.append(cell)

        for  r in range(rows):
            self.grid_rowconfigure(r, weight=1)

        for c in range(columns):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(c, weight=1)

        self.refresh()

    def refresh(self):
        for r in range(self.rows):
            for c in range(self.columns):
                self.widgets[r][c].configure(text=random.randint(0,99))

        # call this function again in 5 seconds
        self.after(5000, self.refresh)

root = tk.Tk()
Table(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tanks Bryan, that is just the way, I wanted it to be. So thanks a lot.